# Can I work in Germany with a foreign (non EU) Engineering degree?

Tags: working-visas, germany, foreign-employment

I've been looking for this for a while, I tried contacting people from the German embassy in my country (Morocco) to know more about it, but unfortunately no clear answer was given, since all they say is everything is clear on our website…

Anyway I recently graduated from Morocco as a GIS engineer and I would like to know if my degree can allow me to work in Germany, and if someone has more information about this, what should I do?

PS: I have a B1 certificate in German from Goethe, is it enough to apply for work there or should I keep learning the language?

Comment: Are you asking whether your degree speciality is in high demand in Germany? Or are you asking how to get a job in Germany (you would need an employment offer to apply for the required residence permit)? And, yes, keep studying the language, should your goal be to work and live in Germany.

Comment: @Dorothy I mean does can I get the work permit if I get a positive feedback on a job offer in germany ? I tried before in Austria ( where the employer agreed to hire me but the Arbeitmarktservice refused since they don't accept non EU graduates to work there ) is it the same thing in Germany ?

Comment: See this answer: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/73646/i-wonder-if-my-phd-from-turkey-is-recognized-in-germany-or-not/73667#73667 use the website I used in that answer to search for the validity of your certificate. Re the other questions, I don't know and you should try searching here first.

Comment: @lafemmecosmique thanks for the link, I got H+ as search result I'll check for more in academia SE

Comment: for anything concerning visas, check expats.SE and for things concerning the job, academia.SE. :)

Comment: You could also use the very useful links on this site, including live chat and email contact http://www.make-it-in-germany.com/en/for-qualified-professionals/visa/quick-check and Bundesagentur für Arbeit which has great resources job search tools https://www.arbeitsagentur.de/web/content/EN/index.htm

Answer (score 3):

It *is* possible to get a visa as a highly-qualified applicant with a non-EU degree (there is no blanket ban or some such) but Germany has a rather bureaucratic system to assess your degree. If your degree is included in the [ZAB database](https://www.kmk.org/themen/anerkennung-auslaendischer-abschluesse.html) and deemed sufficient and you fulfill the other conditions then you could apply for a visa or EU Blue Card. If you cannot find it in there, the ZAB can evaluate it (for a fee). The consulate won't do this for you.

There are rather stringent salary requirements as well for an EU Blue Card but if you qualify, there are no language requirements. There are other routes to immigration (e.g. family reunion) where the degree is not relevant but then you do have to satisfy some language requirements and that does not sound relevant to your situation.

Answer (score -1):

> PS: I have a B1 certificate in German from Goethe, is it enough to apply for work there or should I keep learning the language ?

Whatever level you are, you should always make an effort to keep learning the language. B1 is a good starter position but there are many job adverts which you can find online that specify B2 or even C1 as a minimum requirement.

On the other hand there are also opportunities, particularly in bigger cities, that are advertised in English for companies who work with English as their business language.